# How can I add/remove classes when window is resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, window-resize

I am looking to figure out how to change the attributes of the images when the size of the window is shrunk down to a certain size but it keeps coming up with errors. Anyone have any advice?

This is my code:

```
var img = document.querySelectorAll("img");

 $(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 800 ) {
     img.classList.add("center");
     img.classList.remove("img")
  }
 else {
    img.classList.remove("center");
    img.classList.add("img")
 }
});
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Remember, `querySelectorAll()` returns a collection, not just one result. Also, this is something you can solve with CSS only and media queries

Comment: I am pretty sure you can solve it with js too. but media queries do the job more efficiently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution with CSS only.

```
@media (max-width:800px) {
    .img-class {
         ... center styling ...
    }
}
```

If the window size is less then 800px it will apply the styling you want to the image.

Answer (score 4):

In your code sample, `img` is a collection of DOM elements, returned by `document.querySelectorAll`. You are trying to change their `classList` all at once, but collections do not have a `classList` property. You need to do it for each element, individually:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 800 ) {
        for(var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++){
            imgs[i].classList.add("center");
            imgs[i].classList.remove("img");
        }
    }
    else {
        for(var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++){
            imgs[i].classList.add("img");
            imgs[i].classList.remove("center");
        }
    }
});
```

Or, since you seem to be using jQuery, take advantage of it:

```
var imgs = $("img");

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 800 ) {
        imgs.addClass("center").removeClass('img');
    }
    else {
        imgs.addClass("img").removeClass('center');
    }
});
```

jQuery will apply the changes to each element automatically. Also, `classList` is not supported in IE 9 and below, in case you care about that.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be mixing vanilla JavaScript and JQuery. If you have JQuery available, you might as well use it to set the image classes, e.g.:

```
 var img = $('img');
 $(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 800 ) {
     img.addClass("center").removeClass("img");
  } else {
     img.removeClass("center").addClass("img");
 }
});
```

Otherwise you will need to iterate through your img collection and add/remove individual classes.

Comment: It would be better to chain the methods like `$('img').addClass().removeClass()` so that the `$('img')` selection isn't done twice each time. Or better still, cache it with `var img = $('img')` similar to the OP's code, so that it doesn't have to reselect on each resize.

Comment: Yes, incorporated into the answer.